# Make an image with a percentage width a perfect square using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Hello I have an image in a container that is set to `width: 100%`.

I was wondering if there's any way to can have a height generated to make it a perfect square.

So say the original image is 450px wide and 300px tall.

The css gives it a width of 100% so it stretches and fills the container, but the image remains rectangular.

Is it possible to do some css or jquery trick to generate a height to make this image a perfect suqare?

I don't care if the image gets cropped or stretched out and looks funky, I just need it to be a perfect square.

Thanks!

Comment: it is 'possible' but *either* you will *crop* the image *or* you will *stretch* the image...

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to show what you have done / tried to do?

Comment: @kukkuz It doesnt matter if the image is cropped or stretched, i just need a perfect square

Comment: @OscarSiauw all i have is an image inside a containing div. the image is set to 100% width. thats all ive got so far

Comment: Do you want specific dimension or the image container have a specific dimension?

Comment: the image container is set as a fixed with. the image inside it is set to 100%. the dimension doesnt matter unless its a perfect square. something like 400px by 400px

Comment: Well if container is fixed width then you know what dimension of square is so you can do it with css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do so with the following jQuery

```
var img_width = $('#image').width();
$('#image').css({'height':img_width+'px'});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Quoting the author of the question "I dont care if the image gets cropped or stretched out and looks funky, I just need it to be a perfect square."

Answer (score 3):

So you are free to *stretching out* the image - this can be a CSS solution:

1. Make a square container based on the width by using `padding-top: 100%`
2. *Position* the image absolutely by stretching it out to the square container as desired.

See demo below:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, Bishals answer was the one i was looking for. i gave you an upvote though.

Comment: css seriously need to evolve to make this easier

Answer (score 2):

Using straight CSS you can set width and height to 100vw.

Comment: thanks for you answer, Bishals answer was the one i was looking for. i gave you an upvote.

Comment: me too, that's letting me set the size of an image inside a flexbox list. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't care if the image is cropped or distorted, the layout is simple.

Just add `overflow: hidden` to the container. The image can be any size.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/450/300">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, Bishals answer was the one i was looking for. i gave you an upvote.